# Generating Table Sections from A Property in a List of Objects

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin application and I'm presenting a list of objects in a TableView that are grouped by a specific property of the object.

The property is a date. For each distinct date, I am creating a table section with a header containing said date. Below is the working code to accomplish this, but It's not very elegant.

```
    var trades = new List<ViewCell>();
    Dictionary<string, List<ViewCell>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<ViewCell>>();

    // organizing each object into a dictionary with a key that
    // represents the table header and value for the sections objects
    foreach (var item in completed)
    {
        var date = item.DateClosed.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy");

        if (dict.ContainsKey(date))
        {
            dict[date].Add(new TradeCell(item));
        }
        else {
            dict[date] = new List<ViewCell> { new TradeCell(item) };
        } 
    }

    // looping through the resulting dict to assemble the table             
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<ViewCell>> entry in dict) 
        _table.Root.Add(new TableSection(entry.Key) { entry.Value });
```

### My Question

This gets the job done but I was hoping for a more elegant approach, perhaps using linq?

Comment: Don't make an assumption about the performance - I don't see anything outrageous there. Come back to it if you can prove it's a pain point.

Comment: @RobH thanks, I guess more than performance I felt like there might be a cleaner way to do this. If I revise my question, do you think a more elegant solution is possible, perhaps using linq? If not, I'll go ahead and vote to close this question.

Comment: That's a different question entirely ;) you can use `GroupBy` to do what you want.

Comment: @RobH I'm not super familiar with all of the possibilities of linq, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a more elegant approach... This is certainly more concise:

```
var dict = completed
    .GroupBy(
        item => item.DateClosed.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"), // Key selector
        item => new TradeCell(item)) // Value selector
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

However, you don't actually need the dictionary (that's just to keep the same behaviour as the `foreach`). This should do the job:

```
foreach (var groupOfCells in completed.GroupBy(item => item.DateClosed.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"), item => new TradeCell(item)))
{
    _table.Root.Add(new TableSection(groupOfCells.Key) { groupOfCells .ToList() });
}
```

Remember not to abbreviate names. `dict` doesn't mean anything to anyone.

I'd also suggest grouping by `DateClosed.Date` and converting to a string in your UI layer. I don't know if you need it, but it's much harder to localise if you include hard coded format strings all over the place.

Comment: You're the best, this is exactly what I was looking for